# Как сделать android приложение для планшета?

Tags: android, java

Иконки на планшете выглядят маленькими. В папки закинул иконки: mdpi - 85px, ldpi - 64px, hdpi - 128px, xhdpi - 170 px, xxhdpi - 255 px. Что надо написать в коде, что бы на планшете выглядело так же, как и на телефоне иконками?

Ссылки на скрины приложения. (Ещё нет репутации выше 60, не могу загружать картинки)

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, у планшета вашего плотность mdpi или ldpi, соответственно он берет иконки из mdpi или ldpi папок.

Для планшетов существуют свои собственные модификаторы имен для директорий с ресурсами.   
Без [ссылки](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) на офф. документацию ни как не обойтись. Если не очень понятно, то вот [тут](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_4_-_creating_resources_for_varying_screens/) немного проще.

Если и так не понятно, то своими словами: для планшетов удобно использовать несколько другие модификаторы, основывающиеся не на плотности пикселей, а на физическом размере устройства.

> A 5” tablet / “tweener” device –
> 480dp: such as the Samsung Note
>
> A 7” tablet – 600dp: such as the
> Barnes & Noble Nook
>
> A 10” tablet – 720dp: such as the
> Motorola Xoom

То есть для 5" планшетов можно использовать `drawable-sw480dp`, для 7" - `drawable-sw600dp`, для 10" - `drawable-sw720dp`.

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что и это не панацею для решения вашей задачи, и по этому придется скорее всего размер изображений выставлять при помощи веса (weight)

Comment: Большее спасибо!!!